# Is it possible to implement zero byte check on CSV files in GCS during processing?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating ETL pipelines through the use of Apache-Beam & Dataflow, writing my code in Python.

Currently, my pipeline picks up CSV files matching a predefined naming convention from GCS storage. Currently, my pipeline runs E2E, even if there is no data in the file. The pipeline step simply picks up the file, runs some transformations and places into a different GCS bucket.

I am looking to implement a check that there IS data in the CSV file and for the pipeline to fail if no data is present.

I have been investigating this for a while now and I am struggling to understand how to achieve this.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

In my dataflow job, I have a function that parses the CSV, I attempted to check the line length and if this equals 0, throw relevant exception, but when I tested with an empty CSV file, the code/pipeline still passes.

```
    def parse_csv(element):
        for line in csv.reader([element], delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True):
            if len(line) == 0:
                    logger.error("CSV is empty", exc_info=True)
                    raise Exception("CSV is empty")
            else:
                    return line
```

Comment: I'm assuming here that "element" is the contents of the file? It might be useful to give an example of what an empty file looks like, and what you're expecting. `csv.reader([''], delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)` certainly gives an iterable of a single empty list which would trigger the Exception, but maybe there's a header but no actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [`MatchFiles` transform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.43.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles), and then check the elements of the resulting `PCollection` using the `size_in_bytes` field to raise an exception. If you are running in batch mode in Dataflow, the error will be retried up to 5 times, before the pipeline is stopped.

In any case, do you want the whole pipeline to be stopped when a single file is empty? If you just want to ignore that file, you can just apply a filter, and remove from the `PCollection` all the empty files. That will work even if you have just a single file. The filter will return an empty `PCollection`, and the pipeline will stop as there is no more data to be processed (assuming there is only a single file). If there are several files, only those with some content would be processed.